# Apache Cordova device.uuid

Tags: android, cordova

Straight to the point.

I am trying to get the device.uuid for my android phone using Apache Cordova 3.1.0.

I created a sample add using cordova:

```
cordova-android/bin/create mobile-client
```

The sample app works fine.
Then I added some code to get the device uuid.

But I get the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'uuid' from undefined
```

Here is my javascript:

```
var app = {
    initialize: function () {
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    bindEvents: function () {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },
    onDeviceReady: function () {
        app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
    },
    receivedEvent: function (id) {
        var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
        var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
        var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

        listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
        receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

        console.log('Received Event: ' + id);

        try {
            alert(device.uuid);
        } catch (e) {
            alert(e);
        }

    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the device plugin to your app
just run

```
cordova plugin add --save cordova-plugin-device
```